# ruby libsvm for multiclass issue

Tags: ruby, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

For multiclass prediction, by following the library example given for [this gem](https://github.com/febeling/rb-libsvm) returns slightly inaccurate prediction.

The test set (*The teacher yelled at the student who was late to class but later apologized.*) should have returned `EDUCATION` instead of `HEALTH`

```
require 'libsvm'

# Let take our documents and create word vectors out of them.
#
documents = [ # 0 is JOKES, 1 is EDUCATION and 2 is HEALTH
            [0, "Why did the chicken cross the road? Because a car was coming"],
            [0, "You're an elevator tech? I bet that job has its ups and downs"],
            [0, "Why did the chicken cross the road? To get the worm"],

            [1, "The university admitted more students this year and dropout rate is lessening."],
            [1, "The students turned in their homework at school before summer break."], 
            [1, "The students and teachers agreed on a plan for study."], 

            [2, "The cold outbreak was bad but not an epidemic."],
            [2, "The doctor and the nurse advised be to get rest because of my cold."],
            [2, "The doctor had to go to the hospital."]
         ]

# Lets create a dictionary of unique words and then we can
# create our vectors.  This is a very simple example.  If you
# were doing this in a production system you'd do things like
# stemming and removing all punctuation (in a less casual way).
#
dictionary = documents.map(&:last).map(&:split).flatten.uniq
dictionary = dictionary.map { |x| x.gsub(/\?|,|\.|\-/,'') }

training_set = []
documents.each do |doc|
  @features_array = dictionary.map { |x| doc.last.include?(x) ? 1 : 0 }
  training_set << [doc.first, Libsvm::Node.features(@features_array)]
end

# Lets set up libsvm so that we can test our prediction
# using the test set
#
problem = Libsvm::Problem.new
parameter = Libsvm::SvmParameter.new

parameter.cache_size = 1 # in megabytes
parameter.eps = 0.001
parameter.c   = 10

# Train classifier using training set
#
problem.set_examples(training_set.map(&:first), training_set.map(&:last))
model = Libsvm::Model.train(problem, parameter)

# Now lets test our classifier using the test set
#
test_set = [1, "The teacher yelled at the student who was late to class but later apologized."]
test_document = test_set.last.split.map{ |x| x.gsub(/\?|,|\.|\-/,'') }

doc_features = dictionary.map{|x| test_document.include?(x) ? 1 : 0 }
pred = model.predict(Libsvm::Node.features(doc_features))
puts pred # returns 2.0 BUT should have been 1.0
result = case pred
    when 0.0 then "predicted #{pred} as joke"
    when 1.0 then "predicted #{pred} as education"
    when 2.0 then "predicted #{pred} as health"
end
puts result
```

Issue with the code or need to try other kernel and parameters.

Comment: From the stand point of code, I am not particularly clear on multiclass implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself does not have specific problems. The reason is simply the lack of training data.

Try to use "The university admitted more students this year and dropout rate is lessening.", which is completely the same instance of one in the training set, as a test instance. The program properly classifies it into education.

3 instances for SVM training is not enough. The best way to use more training data and tune parameter C by using cross-validation.